# $|a_n - a_m| \le \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} |a_{k+1} - a_k|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

How to show, that every for sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge_1}$ with $n \gt m$ following holds ?

$$|a_n - a_m| \le \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} |a_{k+1} - a_k|$$

Comment: Triangle inequality.

Comment: Do you believe $|a_n-a_m|=\left|\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}a_{k+1}-a_k\right|$ by telescoping series? If so, Daniel's hint finishes off the proof!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d=(n-m)$. We have $n-(d-1)=m+1 $ and
\begin{align}
|a_n-a_m|
=& |a_n\color{red}{-a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}}-a_m|\\
=& |(a_n-a_{n-1})+a_{n-1}\color{red}{-a_{n-2}+a_{n-2}}-a_m|\\
=& |(a_n-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+a_{n-2}\color{red}{-a_{n-3}+a_{n-3}}-a_m|\\
\vdots\;& \hspace{4cm}\vdots\\
=& |(a_n-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+(a_{n-2}-a_{n-3})+\cdots\color{red}{-a_{n-(d-1)}+a_{n-(d-1)}}-a_m|\\
=& |(a_n-a_{n-1})+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+(a_{n-2}-a_{n-3})+\cdots+(a_{m-1}-a_m)|\\
\end{align}

Comment: so both sides equal each other?